# How Amazon VM import validates kernel version?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, kernel

I'm trying to import a Centos 7.6-1810 VM with the latest stable kernel on Amazon, but the import process fails with the following error:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks    
{
        "Status": "deleted",
        "SnapshotDetails": [
            {
                "Status": "completed",
                "UserBucket": {
                    "S3Bucket": "my-bucket",
                    "S3Key": "packer-import-xxxxxxx.ova"
                },
                "DiskImageSize": 1576340992.0,
                "Format": "VMDK"
            }
        ],
        "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 5.0.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64",
        "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxxxxxxxx"
    }
```

I know the [VM Import/Export Requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html), but it is not so clear about the CentOS supported kernel versions:

> The following operating systems can be imported to and exported from Amazon EC2:
>
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.1-5.11, 6.1-6.9, 7.0-7.6 (6.0 lacks required drivers)
> - CentOS 5.1-5.11, 6.1-6.6, 7.0-7.6 (6.0 lacks required drivers)
>
> Imported Linux VMs should use default kernels for best results. VMs that use custom Linux kernels might not migrate successfully.

**My question is:**

- How Amazon identifies the Kernel version during the VM import process?
- Can I assume that only the default CentOS kernel versions are supported? Or the problem is that I'm using an Elrepo kernel package?
- There is a way to overcome this and use at least the `3.16.65` longterm kernel version? (which contains the latest security fixes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has not provided a complete list of acceptable kernels for several years now. Despite having [specific acceptable minor releases of distros as prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html). So it might not be able to comprehend a RHEL 7 instance with a kernel that isn't 3.10. See Server Fault circa 2016: [What Linux Kernel Versions are Acceptable for AMI Import to Amazon Web Services?](https://serverfault.com/q/776636/241174)

Remove your third party kernels, and add them back after import.

This is merely speculation, but it is not difficult to inspect the file system on a disk image. The distros store their bootloaders and kernels with predictable file names.

Comment: Thanks, John Mahowald. I was able to import a VM using Centos `7.6.1810` + Kernel `3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64` (the latest version available on CentOS/Updates repo by now). It's far from the Longterm/Mainline Kernel releases, but at least addresses critical security issues.

Comment: This doesn't stop you from installing a kernel later. It is a guardrail at import time only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.  I need to export the EC2 instances to VM images after doing some work on them. I have not tested this yet, but I'm pretty sure that the export will fail if I install another Kernel before it :(

Comment: One would have at least thought AWS would have included this in the import requirements: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-role