# How to discover the kernel of Amazon AMIs

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

The AWS documentation says that one can see details of AMIs by running the following:
`aws ec2 describe-images`

However, the returned description does not seem to include the kernel version (for Linux images).

**Is there a way to find out the kernel of an AMI**, other than starting and instance with it and looking inside?

(The reason I am asking is that I am currently trying to import an Ubuntu 18.04 image with `aws ec2 import-image`, but getting a `ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 5.3.0-61-generic`, so I would like to find out which kernels are supported, and I am not satisfied with the answers to the question [What Linux Kernel Versions are Acceptable for AMI Import to Amazon Web Services?](https://serverfault.com/questions/776636/what-linux-kernel-versions-are-acceptable-for-ami-import-to-amazon-web-services)).

EDIT:

As it turns out, the kernels in existing AMIs are not necessarily supported for import. I created an Ubuntu 18.04 instance from an existing AMI, and determined its kernel to be `5.3.0-1023-aws`.

This kernel is [available as an Ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-image-5.3.0-1023-aws), so I installed it on my VM, and tried to import it with `aws ec2 import-image`, without success:

```
 "Status": "deleting",
 "StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 5.3.0-1023-aws",
```

However, even though the original motivation is moot, I am still interested in the original question: how to discover the kernel of Amazon AMIs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Linux Kernel Versions are Acceptable for AMI Import to Amazon Web Services?](https://serverfault.com/questions/776636/what-linux-kernel-versions-are-acceptable-for-ami-import-to-amazon-web-services)

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, I checked that question, but as far as I could tell nobody had figured out how to list supported kernels. My idea is to identify which kernels have already been successfully imported (so a subset of supported kernels)

Comment: That q&a contains the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-operating-systems) to the list of supported operating systems for import. I don't think AWS provides any more information on that.

Comment: @HenrikPingel thanks for the link, but it does not contain information about which kernels are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to check the kernel version of an AMI before you actually create an instance.

After creating an instance you can check with `hostnamectl` :
(works on Ubuntu as well as Amazon Linux 2)

```
$ hostnamectl

   Static hostname: xxxxxxxxxx
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: ec2xxxxxxxx
           Boot ID: xxxxxxxxxxx
    Virtualization: amazon
  Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
       CPE OS Name: cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
            Kernel: Linux 4.14.248-189.473.amzn2.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```